# Check if Hash is included in output

Tags: ruby, syntax

I am trying to check if a specific element is included in an output. I run:

```
results.include? {"_id"=>{"car_id"=>44, "page"=>"5"}, "summarized_time"=>100}
```

but I get an error:

```
Syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting '}'
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: `results` is missing a `}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the curly brackets in this case are interpreted as start of a block. Just put `()` around:

```
results.include?({"_id"=>{"car_id"=>44, "page"=>"5"}, "summarized_time"=>100})
```

Comment: Or, omit the outer `{}`.